# How to setup Google Chrome workspace correctly

Tags: google-chrome, workspace

As I understand it, Google Chrome workspace should allow users to directly modify local files, which are being debugged. According the documentation, the setup process should be:

1) Add local directory to the workspace
2) Map loaded file to the local file

When I followed the described procedure, "localhost" node disappears from the sources treelist (only the mapped local directory is available) and no breakpoints are working. Have a look on the attached picture - left side is before mapping, right side is after mapping (localhost node is missing). Please, can anybody tell me, what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: A recent Chrome update must have broken something. I've been using this for over a year without issue and now I'm having the same problems you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like it was a bug - it works fine after the most recent Chrome update.